# Facebook oAuth user_photos login permission for iOS application

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an app for fetching facebook user_photos[image].

1. I logged into facebook developer's account and created my app. Iam being the admin of the facebook app Iam able to fetch the photos only for my login and not for other login.
2. I submitted my application for review and permissions.Got user_photo permissions which is highlighted in green.
3. I changed my app from Developer mode to LIVE mode.
4. I am able to login through any user successfully and fetch their name and profile pic, as the public profile requires no permission but not able to fetch their user_photos and emailid.

My question is in my code Iam passing publish permission to facebook during login.

self.FBLoginButton.publishPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"user_photos"];

But, when I login through other aoccount oAuth page asks only for public_profile permission and does not provoke to ask user_photos or email permission even if the app permission for user_photos and email is approved and the app is live.

[image: when user login first time to my app it is asking only for public profile permission not for email or user_photo permission even thou I have written code for email and user_photo permission which is approved in review process]
As i am the admin, for my login I am able to fetch the user_photos and emailid.

Comment: Have you tried to get photos after successfully login?

Comment: Have the person testing this remove the app completely from their settings under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, and try again. If it still doesn’t work after that, but the permissions are definitely shown as approved in app dashboard – then file a bug report. (There is sometimes a little glitch where permissions were approved, but they still don’t get asked for by the login dialog, because something is not right internally. They should be able to fix this for you.)

Comment: kb920.....Yes Sir I am able to fetch user_photos successfully for admin of the app. When i add developer in roles i am not able to fetch his user_photos nor able to fetch any other login user_photos except the admin. I even removed the application from developer and tester users setting and tried still not able to fetch

Comment: @Rove are you getting any error?

Comment: No when i am checking the granted permission if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"user_photos"]) {
        NSLog(@"Yes");
        
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No");
        
        
    }........it prints yes for public_profile and no for other permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the login process once again and it started to work. All that i observed here is call AppEvents in app delegate and call read permission in viewDidLoad. Thank you .